# An example/counterexample for convergence in probability for "squeezing sequences" of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $0 < Y_n \le X_n \le Z_n$ a.s. for three sequences of positive random variables.  Assume that we've: $\frac{Y_n}{Z_n}\to _{p}1,$ therefore by [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) also: $\frac{Z_n}{Y_n}\to _{p}1.$ (Here $\to_{p}$ denotes convergence in probability.)

**But does this *alone*  mean $\frac{X_n}{EX_n} \to_{p}1?$ If yes, how to prove it?** So far I couldn't find a counterexample. If this is not true, then can we add some condition to guarantee that  $\frac{X_n}{EX_n} \to_{p}1?$ Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest counterexample is to pick a random variable $W$ such that $W > 0$ and $W \neq \mathbb{E}[W]$ and then set $X_n = Y_n = Z_n = W$ for every $n$. Then $Y_n/Z_n = 1$ but $X_n/ \mathbb{E}[X_n] = W / \mathbb{E}[W]$ does not converge to $1$ in probability.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks for your comment - yes, that's indeed a counterexample! If you find another where $X_n, Y_n, Z_n$ aren't the same random variable, i.e. varies with $n$, that'd be great, and if you do, please feel free to write as an answer. P.S. examples like $Y_n = W -1/n, X_n = W+1/n, Z_n= W + 2/n$ are essentially the same, so perhaps not these ones :)

Comment: What counts as a "different" counterexample? e.g. what if $X_n = W + \varepsilon_n \frac1n$ where $\varepsilon_n$ are iid taking values $\pm 1$ with equal probability (and we can even simultaneously do something similar with $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ so that all three sequences depend on $n$ in the sense that e.g. $Y_{n+1} - Y_n$ isnt deterministic). It feels like you have some extra condition in mind that you're using to disallow counterexamples and its hard to give an answer until you formulate what that is

Comment: @RhysSteele Sorry about that - I'm not always allowed to share in public every single detail of my work for secrecy reasons (although more could be shared privately), and also at times all the detail would make a lot of readers uninterested to read the whole question in the first place. This is why at times I refrain from posting the whole question. I do appreciate your answer though.